# how to use Sinatra-cache?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am developing sinatra web app and 
I would like to cache in server-side with sinatra-cache gem.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-cache/0.3.7/frames

I can install it and it worked.
But now it cache all method.

Next what I want to do is limit a specific method to cache.

For example,

```
get '/cache-me'
```

will be cached but

```
get '/nocache'
```

won't be cached.

How can I control this ?

And also once cached , I want to expire after specified time duration.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable cache *by your self*.

In your `get` methods, just add no-cache parameter **`:cache => false`** to `erb` or `haml` calls. E.g.:

```
# To turn off caching on certain pages:
  get('/nocahce') {
    haml(:view_name, :cache => false) # <- here
  }
```

Take a look on [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-cache/0.3.7/frames#Basic_Page_Caching) for more details. Have a nice day!

Comment: I found cache_expire() but how can I control the time ?

Comment: Oh I found time based expire is not implemented.

Comment: @user3754040 seem to be true. I've check documentation again, and it seems you have to implement cache expiration manually :-(